# Need a jQuery Lightbox plugin that supports $.live() and grouping

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, lightbox

I'm bringing in all of my images via Ajax, and I'm looking for a quick fix for the front-end of this project. I've tried a couple of jQuery lightbox plugins, but I can't seem to get them to perform in a live function (correct me if I'm wrong in thinking I need to do this).

Currently attempting to use Balupton's Lightbox Plugin (can't link because of my being a new user), and after trying all of the examples to no avail, I've attempted it with this (also not working):

```
$('a.lightbox-gallery').live('click', function(){
    $(this).lightbox();
});
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to do and what seems to not be working?

Comment: I want to add lightbox functionality to any images brought into the page via Ajax. So new images are loaded into the page when the user clicks a new category, and when the images are clicked it should bring up a lightbox.
As far as working goes, it doesn't. At all. No matter how I try it. Currently attempting to use ColorBox (http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/), but still no success. I've tried all the examples and also tried putting it into a live function, but no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, I've just fixed it. Fiddled with ColorBox and got it working. I'm running it in a function every time the images change, which didn't seem to work with the previous lightbox plugin but does with this one. Hurray!

Comment: you can always bind your lightbox() to the elements once the AJAX is done with its callback function.

Comment: That is indeed what I ended up doing. I've used this method before, but I got thrown off when it didn't work with a previous lightbox plugin!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) you can hack the lightbox plugin to bind on live events
2) you can call lightbox after ajax is completed, only on new elements:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "url.php",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
        $(data).find('a[rel=lightbox]').lightbox(settings).end().appendTo('#ajaxTarget');
    }
});
```

For `settings` you can use an array to avoid writting same thing twice ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can use colorbox and jquery's live function like this

```
$('a[rel=gallery]').live('click', function() {
  url = this.href; // this is the url of the element event is triggered from
  $.colorbox({href: url});
  return false;
});
```

Comment: i think this is not a solution for grouping ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at the livequery jquery plugin not so bad plugin ;)
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery
you can embed that plugin inside your jquery file and use that as a simple jquery function:

```
$('.ajax-loaded-element').livequery('click',function(){

//do somenthing

});
```